# Input .txt file into .exe file

Tags: python, security, exe

This is part of a very simple exercise. I have an .exe file. When opened it says "Welcome! Enter the key" and asks the user to enter one. When the entry is wrong, it says "Wrong! Try again... " and closes.

I also have a .txt file. I want to run the .txt file against the .exe in a way that enters each entry in the .txt file into the input of the .exe to see if it works. 
Is there a simple way to do this? I have searched for hours but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: check this out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7558/execute-a-command-once-per-line-of-piped-input

Comment: What does the .exe do when the entry is right?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. Bear in mind it was created in python as that is one of the tags, when saving it change the .txt to .exe.

File:

Hello

Bee

Sea

Flea

```
import random
a = True
file = open('route to file location',"r")
file1 = file.read()
file1 = file1.split()
length = len(file1)
randomised = random.random(1,length)
passw = R[randomised]
s = input("Welcome:")
while a is True:
if s == passw:
    a = False
else:
    s = input("Wrong!")
```

Comment: I don't know the correct answer i.e. I don't know the key of the .exe file. I want to find out this key. To do so, I want to run a number of possible options from the .txt file and see if the .txt file has an entry that matches the correct key. If it does, the .exe file will no longer say "wrong! try again". It will probbaly say "correct answer" or similar.

Comment: You might want to do file.readlines() to check multiple values in the file (as long as there is only 1 value per line)

Comment: I will have to put the password in the .py, but when converted you can not tell the password.

Comment: @TommyLawrence what?

Comment: Basically, you cannot use a password system without knowing the physical password

Comment: I tried to allow it more randomisation by using the random function.